# Client Certificate is always null on server side

Tags: c#, certificate, client, iis-express, client-certificates

I read a lot posts about how to send client certificate and did all of them but It is null on server side .

I wrote this code on page mytest.aspx.cs

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    string host = @"http://localhost:57855/Temp/index.aspx";
    string certName = @"C:\cert.pfx";
    string password = @"123456";

    try
    {

        X509Certificate2Collection certificates = new 
        X509Certificate2Collection();

        certificates.Import(certName, password, 
        X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | 
        X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (a, b, c, d) => true;

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(host);
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        req.ClientCertificates = certificates;

        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        string postData = "login-form-type=cert";
        byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        req.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

        Stream postStream = req.GetRequestStream();
        postStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
        postStream.Flush();
        postStream.Close();
        WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();

        Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            while (line != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                line = reader.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        stream.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

and in index.aspx page I wrote this code

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool b = false;
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.ClientCertificate.IsPresent)
        b = true;//b is always  null

}
```

also I'm using IIs express . in applicationhost file in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\IISExpress\config  I change two part

```
 <security>

       <access sslFlags="SslNegotiateCert" />
      ....
      <authentication>
         <clientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="true" />

         <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication  enabled="true">
         </iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication>
         .........
       </security>
```

I installed cert.pfx in mmc=>Certificates/personal/certificates and 
mmc=>certificates (current User)/personal/certificates

but always in index page b is false.

Also i shoud say cert.pfx is not a ssl certificate. It is a digital sign certificate and it has client authentication in cert's enhanskeyusage field

Comment: why you want to load your ssl certificate in code? do you want to use https ?

Comment: I want to client authentication with a  certificate. I need clients  attache a certificate with his http/https request  ( ssl or digital sign certificate....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed client certificate revocation list in server and it is solved

Comment: I am having trouble making this work, so if you can confirm these, it would be great: (1) the client and server certificate need to be from the same CA, (2) IIS should have SSL Settings  switched to `Accept`. With your settings, my web app does not load. I get a 500 HTTP error code. Can this work in combination with Forms Authentication?